# Android xml drawable is bigger first time

Tags: android, android-layout, android-drawable, layer-list

I have two clickable text views with the same drawable left image. When I open fragment first time the first image looks bigger then second one. After clicking on first text view the next fragment is opening and then when I return back two images have the same size. What's wrong? Please help to find out reason of this bug.

[image]

This is my layout:

```
<include layout="@layout/toolbar" />

<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/dmvLawyers"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:clickable="true">

    <TextView
        style="@style/DashBtnStyle"
        android:drawableLeft="@drawable/lawyer_selected"
        android:text="@string/dmv_lawyers"
        android:textAllCaps="false" />

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:paddingRight="@dimen/add_friends_padding_left"
        android:src="@drawable/add" />
</RelativeLayout>

<View
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="@dimen/divider"
    android:background="@color/lineColor" />

<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/tlcLawyers"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:clickable="true">

    <TextView
        style="@style/DashBtnStyle"
        android:drawableLeft="@drawable/lawyer_selected"
        android:text="@string/tlc_lawyers"
        android:textAllCaps="false" />

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:paddingRight="@dimen/add_friends_padding_left"
        android:src="@drawable/add" />
</RelativeLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

This is image drawable (lawyer_selected.xml), where femida is png image, and white background is needed for selected state (button in selected state is green and image should be with white frame):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list   xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item>
    <shape android:shape="rectangle">
        <padding
            android:bottom="@dimen/dash_icon_padding"
            android:left="@dimen/dash_icon_padding"
            android:right="@dimen/dash_icon_padding"
            android:top="@dimen/dash_icon_padding"/>
        <solid android:color="@android:color/white"/>
        <corners
            android:radius="@dimen/dash_icon_radius"/>
    </shape>
</item>
<item android:drawable="@drawable/femida"/>
</layer-list>
```

Image femida.png
[image]

Comment: Where is the femida image in your layout? where have you added it in the layout?In your XML you have the TextView and add image only.

Comment: I added femida image into the post. I set drawable in textview as android:drawableLeft="@drawable/lawyer_selected"

Comment: Check if I you have two lawyer_selected.xml in your layout or not?

Comment: Yes, both text views have android:drawableLeft="@drawable/lawyer_selected", you can see in layout

Comment: No I am asking if there are duplicate lawyer_selected.xml in your layout file.

Comment: Do you mean dublicated drawable files with name lawer_selected.xml ?
No, it's only one file

Comment: If nothing is working out ,make a separate xml,take two imageviews,put feminda.png as their src  and check whether the image size are same or not,I think this checking will solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Just use nested LinearLayout instead and use android:layout_weight="1" or any required value to you and it will work for sure.

**In your case it will be 1 only, while the main parent LinearLayout can have wrap_content as height